# Visual studio "Catastrophic failure" error: can't view form with designer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms

I have a CLR/C++ project, with many controls on a single form.
For a few days I've been unable to view this form with the designer, I get the error:

> "To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:
> Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))".
> If I click "Ignore and continue" the designer opens on an empty form.

The project builds fine and even runs, but I can't design the UI.

I use VS2019 16.11.28.

What I've done:

- Rebuilt then modified VS installation
- Completely uninstalled and reinstalled VS
- Changed the target .NET framework version of the project (was 4.5.2) to 4.7 and 4.8
- Added a new form in this project: there's no option to open it with the designer and its icon is that of a regular .h file
- The same thing happens when I create a new CLR project and add a form: no option to view the designer
- I can still open forms in the designer, with other existing projects (but they are VB projects and the forms have only a few controls)

I'm really stumped.

---

Other information, I don't know if that can help or if it's even related:

- The ActivityLog.xml file shows many errors such as this one, with (I'm guessing) all the controls in the toolbox, here an example with button:

> Item 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' has an invalid assembly name (invalid or missing version): 'System.Windows.Forms, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken  "

- This file also shows errors like this:

> "Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft.NETFramework) as a version"

- Call stack for the error:
  at EnvDTE.CodeFunction.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart Part)
  at Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeParser.OnMethodPopulateStatements(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  at System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod.get_Statements()
  at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
  at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

Comment: Have you tried the latest Visual Studio 2022? Maybe the problem was fixed in the past. Try creating a new C++CLR project. If the problem persists, please report it to the [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/dotnet/report).

Answer (score 0):

Often this happens, when your user controls throws exceptions, while being loaded from the designer.

To find such issues:

- Start Visual Studio with your project, let's call this one #1
- Launch another instance of Visual Studio (#2)
- In #2 select Debug - Attach to process - select VS #1
- In #2, in Exception settings, select all "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"
- In #1, open the problematic control in the designer

The designer will now trigger an exception, VS #2 should detect that one, and point directly to the problematic code.